# Source code line from BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at

Tags: linux, kernel, debugging, system-calls

I am debugging a custom system call I wrote, and I keep seeing this error in the kernel log:  "BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at (number)". Is there a way to derive the source code line with the error from the number it gives me (example: 0000000000000736)?

Comment: The kernel log is surely not so short, there should be a lot of more important things (f.e. stack trace) before it.